# unable to start docker : no such container after save and load image

Tags: docker

I have saved docker image and then load image.

```
$ sudo docker load -i e7bdb77cdcd8.tar
```

the images is loaded correctly
however i cannot start docker.

```
$ docker start e7bdb77cdcd8
Error response from daemon: No such container: e7bdb77cdcd8
Error: failed to start containers: e7bdb77cdcd8
```

Answer (score 0):

[docker start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) is used to start one or more stopped containers.

After you use [docker load -i](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/#examples), it should load the artifact as a new docker image, you could see it using `docker image ls`.

Then, you should use `docker run $your_loaded_image` to run it.